# Sorting an array by Parent-Child

Tags: ios, nsarray, sorting

I have an array of custom objects. The objects represent segments in a binary file.
The property `loc` holds the objects own location in the file, where `prev` holds the location of the "previous" object. In this context "previous" and "next" doesn't necessarily mean that the objects occur after each other in the file.
The first object has `prev = 0`. The last object has no following object holding its location as `prev`.

How do I achieve such kind of sorting? Number of objects is initially not known.

```
//My custom object
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger loc, prev;

@end

//In the implementation of some other class
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

{// order should be 6
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 3000;
    obj.prev = 111;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
{// order should be 2
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 2000;
    obj.prev = 222;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
{// order should be 4
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 333;
    obj.prev = 4000;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
{//  order should be 1
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 222;
    obj.prev = 5000;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
{//  order should be 5
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 111;
    obj.prev = 333;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
{// order should be 3
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 4000;
    obj.prev = 2000;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
{// order should be 0
    MyObject *obj = [MyObject new];
    obj.loc = 5000;
    obj.prev = 0;
    [array addObject:obj];
}
```

Comment: What does the array contain exactly?

Comment: Objects, each holding its ID and Parent ID.

Comment: This is a very strange problem. Do you know which segment is the last one? Or the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Try using lexicographical sorting:

```
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 parentID] < [obj2 parentID] {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ([obj1 parentID] > [obj2 parentID] {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if ([obj1 ID] < [obj2 ID] {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ([obj1 ID] > [obj2 ID] {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Comment: My problem was pretty poor described. I rephrased the question.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I got it.

```
NSMutableArray *unordered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSMutableArray *ordered = [NSMutableArray new];

for(MyObject *myObj in array)
{
    if(!myObj.prev)
    {
        [orderedTables addObject:myObj];
        [unorderedTables removeObject:myObj];
        break;
    }
}

int counter = 0;
while(unordered.count && counter < ordered.count)
{
    MyObject *obj1 = [ordered objectAtIndex:counter++];

    for(int i = 0; i < unordered.count; ++i)
    {
        MyObj *obj2 = [unordered objectAtIndex:i];

        if(obj2.prev == obj1.loc)
        {
            [ordered addObject:obj2];
            [unordered removeObject:obj2];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: H2C03's answer provides you with a good solution, simple to understand and using fast (native) sorting algorithm. You are implementing a sorting algorithm by yourself and it is the slowest (on wikipedia called "naive") sorting algorithm.

Comment: Actually, looking at your question again, this is not sorting at all. You need indexing, e.g. using `NSDictionary`.